# Fechar modal Ant Design com ESC

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso fechar um modal do Ant Design com ESC.
Estou usando React.
Tenho essa função que fecha o modal, mas estou com dificuldades de implementar no código.
Podem me ajudar?

```
handleOk = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada na [documentação](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-basic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse comportamento deveria estar ocorrendo por padrão, verifique se não está passando a prop *keyboard* como false, se estiver vc pode omitir ou passar a mesma como true.

Segundo a documentação:

keyboard:*Boolean* -> Whether support press esc to close. **Default value**: true

```
    <Modal
      keyboard
      title="Basic Modal"
      visible={this.state.visible}
      onOk={this.handleOk}
      onCancel={this.handleCancel}
      okButtonProps={{ disabled: true }}
      cancelButtonProps={{ disabled: true }}
    >
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Opa. Eu consegui aqui.